# Messed up my user account while probably changing default shell, need fix please

Tags: permissions, login, 19.10, user-management

I can't exactly explain what's gone wrong, but i was trying to change (back) my default shell via `chsh -s` and was confronting the "PAM: Authentication failure". Then I read and tried different workarounds here and there and finally messed up my system such that initially as I logged out of session, Ubuntu's initial setting wizard came up (apparently there was no user defined)!

Then I tried to reboot and got stock in the boot screen. I fixed it and could get to login screen, but my user was not listed and login via manual typing of username/password was not possible; had to create a new one (again via init wizard).

After logging in as new user, I set a new password for old user (`sudo passwd olduser`) an this time I could finally log into my olduser account by manually typing username and new password (Still not listed at login)

<strike>Now I have a weird situation. I have no data lost but my good old user is somehow not complete…</strike> I don't know where to look for missing parts… some apps ask for keychain password, which i can fix later i guess. TL;DR: first of all I need to have the user normally listed at login screen

output of `~$ getent passwd olduser`
`roxch:x:1000:1000:MyName:/home/olduser:/usr/bin/fish`

Comment: *"I have no data lost but my good old user is somehow not complete"* please try to be more specific. What issue are you trying to solve, exactly?

Comment: well first of all the user is not listed at the login screen… (not solved yet)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `getent passwd olduser`

Comment: here you are @steeldriver